# Emploi des temps

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, mode-grammatical

Pour quelles raisons plusieurs temps sont soit peu employés, soit ont pratiquement disparu ?

Il me semble que le passé composé a quasiment remplacé le passé simple. J'ai lu plusieurs thèses qui ne comportent pas de passé simple. Idem pour le couple plus-que-parfait/passé antérieur.

Est-ce la difficulté du passé simple ? Ou alors parce que plusieurs verbes au passé simple ont des formes identiques à celles du présent de l'indicatif ? Par exemple: dire (je dis, tu dis, il dis), rire, suffire, etc.

Quelques livres de conjugaison que je possède évoquent l'impératif passé mais les livres de grammaire n'en parlent pas.

Pareillement, on rencontre à la fois dans les livres de grammaire et dans les livres de conjugaison l'imparfait et le plus-que-parfait du subjonctif, or, on apprend que les deux sont extrêmement peu utilisés. Pourquoi ont-ils disparu et ne les voie-t-on que dans des textes littéraires ?

On parle parfois des temps dits surcomposés mais un seul de mes livres en parle en y dédiant trois ou quatre lignes. Est-ce que ce ne sont pas des temps officiels ?

Comment: C'est quoi un temps "officiel" ?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Un temps qui existe dans les grammaires de référence comme celle de Grevisse ou bien dans les grammaires pour les écoliers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C'est une très bonne question liée à l'évolution de la langue et de la société française...
En effet, le passé simple n'est presque plus employé à l'oral en France. Dans mon entourage, personne ne l'emploie à moins de vouloir donner un certain style à la discussion, comme lorsqu'un conteur raconte une histoire par exemple.

Je pense que cela vient du fait qu'il est plus difficile à apprendre que le passé composé car de nombreux verbes (du 3e groupe notamment) ont une conjugaison qui leur est propre (ex: je fis, je dûs, j'eus...)

Quand j'étais plus jeune, on nous l'apprenait à l'école et on l'employait un bien plus à l'oral (et à l'écrit) mais je ne sais pas si ça se fait encore car très peu de gens l'utilisent.

Concernant les autres temps, c'est pareil. Plus complexes, plus désuets et plus du tout utilisés à l'oral donc ils disparaissent... 
Je trouve cependant que c'est intéressant de les connaitre afin d’être à l'aise lorsqu'on lit des textes littéraires.